# The word Array is displayed instead of the database entry

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

I am trying to print selected product names from my database, however all i see is the word "Array" instead of the product name. It is displayed as many times as the number products it finds, and that number is correct, but it only shows "Array"...

Here's my code:

```
public function lookup($product)
    {

        $camera = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM products WHERE type = 'Camera' ");

        $laptop = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM products WHERE type = 'Laptop' ");


        $data = array();

        switch($product)
        {
            case 'camera' : 
            foreach ($camera->result() as $row)
            {
                $entry = array();
                $entry['name'] = $row->name;
                $data[] = $entry;
            }
            return $data; break;

            case 'laptop' :
            foreach ($laptop->result() as $row)
            {
                $entry = array();
                $entry['name'] = $row->name;
                $data[] = $entry;
            }
            return $data; break;

        }   
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code that prints the product on the screen?

Comment: no one has answered any of your previous questions correctly?

Comment: Let's see the code that outputs this result. Odd are you are doing something like <?php echo lookup(); ?>, which returns an array. You need to set the key... <?php $foo = lookup(); echo $foo['name']; ?>

Comment: Not an answer, since we can't see how you're outputting it. But it seems like you're doing extra work. Check to see if $product is camera or laptop before the query, then use either $product or a new variable in the query. Then you only need to run 1 query and you can eliminate that switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to `echo` an array? You should probably try `var_dump($array_var);` or use a loop such as `foreach` to traverse the array values and print/echo each one.

Comment: This is correct.  I like to use the print_r function.  In some of my code, I create a print_ar() function that echos "<pre>" and "</pre>" before and after a print_r call.  That makes the browser display the printed array nice enough for my purposes.